# Why did unattended-upgrade remove lvm2 and libreadline5?

Tags: upgrade, lvm

I installed Ubuntu 18.10 last week on a new host with LVM. It has one SSD with boot and root in one VG, and then I added one HDD in a different VG containing `/home and /media`.

A day or so later, after I had installed a bunch of additional applications and configuration, the `unattended-upgrade` script removed the packages `lvm2` and `libreadline5`. Now my system won't boot up, because no lvm tools.

Why would it do this? I found this in the `/var/log/apt/history.log`, but I don't see any reasoning anywhere. I can't reinstall it at this point, so I may have to reinstall from scratch again.

Output from `/var/log/apt/history.log` from the unattended-upgrade of 10/30 through the unattended-upgrade removal on 11/01:

```
Start-Date: 2018-10-30  06:26:47
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: python-paramiko:amd64 (2.4.1-0ubuntu3.1, 2.4.1-0ubuntu3.2)
End-Date: 2018-10-30  06:26:48

Start-Date: 2018-10-30  06:26:50
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: tzdata:amd64 (2018f-0ubuntu0.18.10, 2018g-0ubuntu0.18.10)
End-Date: 2018-10-30  06:26:50

Start-Date: 2018-11-01  06:17:54
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: distro-info-data:amd64 (0.38, 0.38ubuntu0.1)
End-Date: 2018-11-01  06:17:54

Start-Date: 2018-11-01  06:17:56
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (7.61.0-1ubuntu2, 7.61.0-1ubuntu2.2)
End-Date: 2018-11-01  06:17:56

Start-Date: 2018-11-01  06:17:58
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libcurl4:amd64 (7.61.0-1ubuntu2, 7.61.0-1ubuntu2.2), curl:amd64 (7.61.0-1ubuntu2, 7.61.0-1ubuntu2.2)
End-Date: 2018-11-01  06:18:00

Start-Date: 2018-11-01  06:18:02
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: chromium-browser:amd64 (70.0.3538.67-0ubuntu0.18.10.1, 70.0.3538.77-0ubuntu0.18.10.1), chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra:amd64 (70.0.3538.67-0ubuntu0.18.10.1, 70.0.3538.77-0ubuntu0.18.10.1), chromium-browser-l10n:amd64 (70.0.3538.67-0ubuntu0.18.10.1, 70.0.3538.77-0ubun
tu0.18.10.1)
End-Date: 2018-11-01  06:18:07

Start-Date: 2018-11-01  06:18:08
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libgs9:amd64 (9.25~dfsg+1-0ubuntu1, 9.25~dfsg+1-0ubuntu1.1), ghostscript:amd64 (9.25~dfsg+1-0ubuntu1, 9.25~dfsg+1-0ubuntu1.1), ghostscript-x:amd64 (9.25~dfsg+1-0ubuntu1, 9.25~dfsg+1-0ubuntu1.1), libgs9-common:amd64 (9.25~dfsg+1-0ubuntu1, 9.25~dfsg+1-0ubuntu1.1)
End-Date: 2018-11-01  06:18:10

Start-Date: 2018-11-01  06:18:12
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Remove: lvm2:amd64 (2.02.176-4.1ubuntu3), libreadline5:amd64 (5.2+dfsg-3build2) 
End-Date: 2018-11-01  06:18:15
```

**EDIT:**
Could this intry from `/var/log/apt/eipp.log.xz` be the cause?

```
Package: libdevmapper1.02.1
Architecture: amd64
Version: 2:1.02.145-4.1ubuntu3
APT-ID: 2201
Multi-Arch: same
Status: installed
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.22), libselinux1 (>= 1.32), libudev1 (>= 183)
Conflicts: libdevmapper1.02
Breaks: liblvm2app2.2 (<< 2.02.122), lvm2 (<< 2.02.122)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the entire day of output from that log, plus all output *before* that day to the previous run of u-u.